# Illustrator and CMYK or RGB mode when using Pantone colors?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, cmyk, rgb, pantone

Should Illustrator be set to CMYK or RGB mode when using Pantone colors? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

CMYK.

The Pantone matching system is a **print production ink system**. Print production always uses CMYK as a basis. Pantone colors have absolutely no basis in the RGB spectrum.

Comment: I am working with this Green Neon Pantone color: 802 C. In RGB color Mode It looks the way I like it to be printed. https://thefinalbossdinorpg.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/screen-shot-2014-11-19-at-20-20-11.png. But when I change to CMYK color mode the Pantone color looks opaque https://thefinalbossdinorpg.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/screen-shot-2014-11-19-at-20-20-32.png . What should I do?

Comment: ... and that's why you need to use CMYK mode. RGB mode is *not realistic* where Pantone colors are concerned.

Answer (score 1):

When doing anything for print, you should use CMYK. RGB colors have a much wider gamut, so what you see on screen might look more vibrant, but it won't print that way, especially when directly translating a print-only color model to a screen-only color model. Even software-performed RGB -> CMYK and the reverse can be iffy sometimes.

You also have to take into account that CMYK colors will look comparatively dull on a monitor to anything else on screen because of the color gamut difference; on a printed product, the audience will only be seeing colors within the CMYK spectrum, so it won't be out of place or expectation.